# Add Hyperlink to TextBlock from other Thread by SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to add Hyperlink to TextBlock (someTextBlock) by SynchronizationContext (someSynchronizationContext).

```
public void SomeDelegateMethod () {

    Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink (); // Some Hyperlink
    hl.NavigateUri = new Uri (link);
    hl.Inlines.Add (text);

    someSynchronizationContext.Send (d => someTextBlock.Text += link + "\r\n", null); // This line works flawlessly
    someSynchronizationContext.Send (d => someTextBlock.Inlines.Add (hl), null); // This line doesn't wokrs (Exception: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it)
}
```

**Exception: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

Please tell me how does it right.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: On which thread was someSynchronizationContext created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create instances of **UI Controls** and use it in a different `UI thread` even if you use `SynchronizationContext`.

An element created in one UI thread can't be put into the logical/visual tree of another element which is created on a different UI thread.

It is also recommended that you just use `MVVM` pattern.

What I would do is in your `TextBlock` DataTemplate (XAML) is to make it a `HyperLink` and on my `ViewModel` where I need a second thread to create my **NavigationUri** and **Text** so that I can marshall the UI updates from a different thread without using `SynchronizationContext`.